# Change nav menu styling on hover

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, navigation, toggle

I have a jQuery toggle nav menu as a secondary nav on a page.

I want to have a "hover" backgound-color on the titles (top level navigation with arrow).

http://awesomescreenshot.com/07c1w39kc1

I tried to use:

```
.title1 a{
    background-color:#FC3; 
}
.title1 p a:hover,.on p a{
    background-color:#ae0606; 
}
```

The hover on the Titles should match the subtitles hover in width and height,

Here is the jQuery code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.title1').click(function() {    

        $('.title1').removeClass('on');    
        $('.content2').slideUp('normal'); 

        if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {    
            $(this).addClass('on');    
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        }

    });

});
</script>
```

Url to test page, http://planeta.se/nordcharkLast/recept-2/

Comment: Any feedback on our responses?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean replace the red with the yellow then you'll need to change 
`background-color:#ae0606;` to
`background: url(images/subHover.jpg) repeat-x;`

but if you want to replace the yellow with red then replace `background: url(images/subHover.jpg) repeat-x;` with `background-color:#ae0606;`

also, title 3 4 and 5 don't have a working hover. Title 4 is set like `<div class="title1 on"><p>Titel 4</p></div>` when it should be `<div class="title1"><p>Titel 4</p></div>` and to get the hover to work you need to add the `<a> link stuff </a>`

Comment: But why does the "arrow" dissapear on hover? is that possible to fix?

Comment: the only way I can think of is if you use a color instead of a hover image `.title1 a p:hover, .on a p {
background: url(images/arrow-toggle.png) 0 3px no-repeat #f00 !important;`

I'm looking for the yellow color now

Comment: `.title1 a p:hover, .on a p {
background: url(images/arrow-toggle.png) 0 3px no-repeat #fcdf6a!important;`

Comment: ok, thanx! I´m usign a sprite image now.. but last question. Is it possible to add active state? Right now the active and hover are the same..

Comment: I just saw this and came to answer, but it looks like you already got it! Good job!